# Laravel Eloquent defined relationship not working

Tags: laravel

In the `posts` migration:

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('created_by')->nullable();
$table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
```

In the `Post` model

```php
public function created_by()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\User::class, 'created_by');
}
```

In the controller fetching the posts:

```php
$posts = Post::with('created_by')->get();
```

In the blade view

```php
{{ $post->created_by->name }}
```

But I get: `Attempt to read property "name" on int` as `$post->created_by` is `1` for instance, but not the full model loaded as a relationship which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! Please post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You already have an answer but just adding a point.

Default props in Laravel are always represented By camelCase, so when you want to access something as prop you can follow this as rule of thumb! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out in the question, `created_by` is `1`, i.e. the ID representation of the `User` instance that created the `Post` instance, and the error properly reflects this (since what essentially equates to `1->name` is not valid PHP code). To handle this, use a different name for your relationship than the column being used as the Foreign Key reference:

```php
// `createdBy`, `createdByUser`, `user`, etc. etc., as long as it is different than `created_by`
public function createdBy() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
}
```

Method names should be `camelCase`, `createdBy`, instead of `created_by`. Additionally, you don't need the full namespace if they are shared (i.e. `App\Models\Post` and `App\Models\User` have the same `App\Models` namespace, so `User::class` is all you need in the definition.

Now, with this code, you should be able to call:

```php
{{ $post->createdBy->name }}
```